# Android Studio incremental obfuscation causing error: cannot find symbol class

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate a project with 2 modules.
The first module is independent and the second is using the first module.
Each module is a library so I can't merge both to the same aar.
The first module build and obfuscated as expected, but when I'm trying to build the second module the build script fail with the above message (error: cannot find symbol class) and cannot find the obfuscated classes.
I've try to add `-applymapping` flag but proguard run only after the build so it doesn't help.
How can I build my project without the need to run proguard manually for every module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up by running command line the unpack the arr, run proguard and repack everything